# MUI Menu card don't follow the Select component

Tags: html, css, reactjs, material-ui

I have an issue in material ui, I'm using `select` component, a `menu card` appears when clicking on that select, the problem is the `menu card` don't follow the position of `select component`, just like what you'll see here ↓:

[image]

the picture above is normal and it looks good, but when I scroll, the menu card stay fixed on its position like this, I want it to follow the select position

[image]

here is the select component code:

```
                  <Select
                    labelId="skills"
                    id="skills"
                    name="skills"
                    label={t('skills')}
                    multiple
                    value={values.skills}
                    onChange={handleChange}
                    error={touched.skills && Boolean(errors.skills)}
                    renderValue={selected => (
                      <Box
                        sx={{ display: 'flex', flexWrap: 'wrap', gap: 0.5 }}
                      >
                        {selected.map(value => (
                          <Chip
                            key={value}
                            label={value}
                            sx={{ height: '20px' }}
                          />
                        ))}
                      </Box>
                    )}
                    MenuProps={{
                      PaperProps: {
                        style: {
                          maxHeight: 48 * 4.5 + 8,
                          width: 250,
                        },
                      },
                      disableScrollLock: true,
                    }}
                  >
                    {skills.map(name => (
                      <MenuItem
                        key={name}
                        value={name}
                        style={getStyles(name, personName, theme)}
                      >
                        {name}
                      </MenuItem>
                    ))}
                  </Select>
```

I know I'm using `disableScrollLock: true` in `MenuProps` because when it's false the scrollbar in the right hide, I don't wan't it to be hidden even if the menu card is opened

Thank you in advance